# Good approach to creating simple model validation in java

Tags: java, validation

What approach and structure should I use to create a model validation system in java, similar to the model validation in C#?

I'd like to be able to mark or annotate a field as being required or be able to set a constraint (length, max size, etc), and be able to provide a message.

What would a good approach be in order to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the bean validation framework [JSR-303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303), here's a link to an article http://java.dzone.com/articles/bean-validation-and-jsr-303

In the case for Android, see Richard Kennards comment on this article,
http://java.dzone.com/articles/jsr-303-and-jvm-web-framework

> Hi Matt,
>
> [Metawidget](http://metawidget.org/) has JSR-303 support.
>
> Because Metawidget wires up other frameworks, this means that
>   Metawidget effectively adds JSR-303 support to Android, GWT, JSF (not
>   only RichFaces), JSP, Spring MVC, Struts, Swing and SWT.

Comment: I don't think that will work for me, as I'm not using Java EE. (I'm trying to use this for Android development as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Java EE has introduced some built in [bean validation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) like `@Null, @NotNull` which definitely can be extended to match your custom validation if required be.